# Shorter cast PsObject[long] to DateTime

Tags: c#, powershell, casting

I'm curious. Is it possible to cut this code?

```
        using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShell.AddScript("Get-ADUser " + Login + " -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Select -Expand \"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed\"");
            Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
            psObjects = powerShell.Invoke();

            long PasswordExpireTemp = long.Parse(psObjects.FirstOrDefault().ToString());
            userViewModel.PasswordExpire = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(PasswordExpireTemp);
        }
```

I mean, skip creating **long PasswordExpireTemp**.
PsObject is Object[long.
userViewModel.PasswordExpire is DateTime?

Answer (score 1):

sure, if you continue to do the work in PowerShell:

powerShell.AddScript("[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc((Get-ADUser " + Login + " -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Select -Expand \"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed\"")));

However, both bits of code will return a datetime of:  Monday, January 1, 1601 12:00:00 AM; under the conditions where 'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' is '0' or null:

> If any of the ADS_UF_SMARTCARD_REQUIRED, ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD,
>   ADS_UF_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT, ADS_UF_SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT,
>   ADS_UF_INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT bits is set in TO!userAccountControl,
>   then TO!msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
>
> Else, if TO!pwdLastSet = null, or TO!pwdLastSet = 0, then
>   TO!msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed = 0.
>
> Else, if Effective-MaximumPasswordAge = 0x8000000000000000, then
>   TO!msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (where
>   Effective-MaximumPasswordAge is defined in [MS-SAMR] section 3.1.1.5).
>
> Else, TO!msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed = TO!pwdLastSet +
>   Effective-MaximumPasswordAge (where Effective-MaximumPasswordAge is
>   defined in [MS-SAMR] section 3.1.1.5).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f9e9b7e2-c7ac-4db6-ba38-71d9696981e9

Hi Hoshie, you're right, I was missing parenthesis wrapping the inner command in it's own.  As far as possible errors, please see the edit below:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-ADUser [MyUserAccount] -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Select-Object -ExpandProperty msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed) 
9223372036854775807

        PS C:\Windows\system32> [int64]::MaxValue 9223372036854775807

        PS C:\Windows\system32> [datetime]::MaxValue

        Friday, December 31, 9999 11:59:59 PM

        PS C:\Windows\system32> [datetime]::MaxValue.ToFileTimeUtc()
     2650467743999999999

        PS C:\Windows\system32> [datetime]::MaxValue.ToFileTime() 
    2650467743999999999
```

So, the problem you're running into is that the value that is returned from this property can be LARGER than the maximum possible value accepted by the DateTime object--refer to the MSDN article for all of the conditions where this value returns the Int64.MaxValue of '9223372036854775807' (0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF).

You have to handle this possibility either in PowerShell or C#.  Here is a sample of how it *might* be solved in PowerShell:

```
$var = (Get-ADUser [MyUserName] -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Select-Object -ExpandProperty msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed)

if ($var -and $var -ne [int64]::MaxValue) {
    ## Do something with the value
} else {
    ## Value is either $null or -eq to the Max Value of a Signed 64-bit integer
}

## OR

if ($var -and $var -ge 0 -and $var -lt [datetime]::MaxValue.ToFileTimeUtc()) {
    $true
    ## Do something
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct entry? PsObjest is null. I found an error at the end with ) and I tried ...Computed\")"); but still null.

Comment: @Hoshie, I was missing wrapping the Get-ADUser in an extra pair of ().  However, you have another problem with the multitude of conditions where this value can come back representing the max-value of a 64-bit which will throw an exception and not convert to a DateTime type.